# RegEx URL For Scrapy

Tags: regex

Trying to construct the RegEx for URLs of this format: http://graphics.stltoday.com/apps/payrolls/salaries/23_10/; in the general case this would be http://graphics.stltoday.com/apps/payrolls/salaries/##_##/; the first and second numbers can both be 1 or 2 digits 0-9.

I have /apps/payrolls/salaries/[0-9]_[0-9]/$, but I'm not sure how to allow either 1 or 2 digits for each number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `x{A,B}` RegExp pattern, where A is the minimum of `x` you may have, and B the maximum. so for you:

```
/apps/payrolls/salaries/\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}/$
```

`\d` means that you want a digit, it is the same as writing `[0-9]`.

You can also ommit A or B, for instance `x{2,}` will match 2 or more `x`. And there are some special characters that you can use as shortcut:

- `*` for `{0,}`
- `+` for `{1,}`
- `?` for `{0,1}`

You can try all of these [here](//regex101.com).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `+` which mean match one ore more time ([check regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRebML/1)):

```
/apps/payrolls/salaries/[0-9]+_[0-9]+/$
-----------------------------^------^
```

If you want to match `one to two` numbers you can use `[0-9]{1,2}` ([check regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYHAWh/1)):

```
/apps/payrolls/salaries/[0-9]{1,2}_[0-9]{1,2}/$
-----------------------------^^^^-------^^^^
```

**Note** you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`